# Python - Having trouble with IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

Thanks in advance for your answers. Ive tried to research my own answer to this problem for hours with no avail. I'm now asking for advice not the answer perhaps as it is an assignment question for university.

I have a program that stores a set of data in single line records. This is saved in a file named 'sales.txt'

There is a variable (customerIDInput) brought over from another function which is basically the customer ID.

My program is supposed to search the records line by line, finding every record that has the 'customerIDInput' in index 0.

I am getting an error on what I would assume is the last repeat of the loop. Index out of range. I have initially thought this was the last (\n) and therefore not having any index at all... However I have put in a rstrip(\n') and the problem has not been solved.

I realize that I am new to python and the answer is probably very simple however I'm in over my head I think and it seems its time to ask you wise people here :)

Attached is the function I am having difficulty with.

```
def searchFile ():

sales = open('sales.txt', 'r')    
transaction = 'START'

while transaction != ' ':

    transaction = sales.readline()
    transactionStrip = transaction.rstrip('\n')        
    transaction_list = transactionStrip.split()

    if transaction_list[0] == str(customerIDInput):    
        customerEntry = transaction_list 
        print('matching records are: ',customerEntry)

sales.close()
```

Comment: @Samane Please don't go around removing only the greetings from posts. Yes, the greetings need to be removed, but can you also look for other improvements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `readline` method on file objects will return an empty string when you reach the end of the file. When you `split` the empty string, you'll get an empty list, which has no first element. This is why `transaction_list[0]` gives you an `IndexError` at the end of the file.

There are a few different ways you could fix this issue. Keeping close to your current code, you could adjust your `while` loop's condition to look for `transaction` being an empty string (rather than a string with a single space) and read one line ahead:

```
transaction = sales.readline()    # read first line
while transaction != "":
    # do stuff with non-empty transaction line

    transaction = sales.readline()  # read next line
```

However, a more natural way to iterate over the lines in a file is to simply use a `for` loop directly on the file object:

```
for transaction in sales:
    # do stuff
```

Iterating this way will stop automatically at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply check if such an index exists by calling `if transaction_list:` (which checks if there is any item in it) before actually trying to get `transaction_list[0]` to avoid the `IndexError`.